# Not Sure How To Use Backticks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, atom-editor

This is my first time using backticks, and I'm not able to get my function to work in either FireFox or Chrome. Here is my code:

```
function makeLetter(fName, lName) {
  return `Dear ${fName} ${lName},
    How are you today?`;
}
```

when I put in `makeLetter(hello, world)` I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: hello is not defineddebugger eval code:1:1
<anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `makeLetter(“hello”, “world”);` it’s looking for a variable or fn that’s not define. Make them strings if you don’t have variables set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks are used just fine. The JavaScript interpreter complains because it doesn't know about `hello` or `world`. You passed them in as variables, you need to pass them as strings instead. Like this:

```js
function makeLetter(fName, lName) {
  return `Dear ${fName} ${lName},
    How are you today?`;
}

console.log(makeLetter('John', 'Doe'));
```

Tip: Since your function returns a string, I used `console.log` to print out the message.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand much better. And I'll make sure to use your console.log tip as well!